# Recursive fill form with all options

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to scrape a webpage by dynamicaly filling in the forms, but I'm finding it hard to get a starting point.

The forms on the site have a different number of select items on each form so my plan was to build a recursive function that:

- navigate to the last select
- change the value till it reaches the last
- change the value of the (last select-1)
- navigate to the last select
- change the value till it reaches the last
- and so on till every possible value has passed

In the end I want to make a table so that for example this form :

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="Width">
            <label>Width :</label>
            <select name="Width" onBlur="getPrice()">
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div id="Height">
            <label>Height :</label>
            <select name="Height" onBlur="getPrice()">
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div id="Color">
            <label>Color :</label>
            <select name="Color" onBlur="getPrice()">
              <option value="red">red</option>
              <option value="blue">blue</option>
              <option value="white">white</option>
              <option value="black">black</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div id="price">Price =</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

will give a table like

```
# | width | height | color
==|=======|========|======
1 | 1     | 1      | red
2 | 1     | 1      | blue
3 | 1     | 1      | white
4 | 1     | 1      | black
5 | 1     | 2      | red
6 | 1     | 2      | blue
7 | 1     | 2      | white
8 | 1     | 2      | black
etc......
```

Is this doable in a recursive function or is there a better solution for this?

Comment: Do you just need to build a table of the possible select combinations, or *do* something for each of them?

Comment: I just need to scrape the contents, but there is a onBlur event on the selects that trigger a function that fills a div with a price. So I need to get that value too. So I really need to do the select changes. I changed the code.